# Scale polygon from One Side

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I want to Make Polygon(Rectangle) Smaller and I write This Function that works Fine For Reduce Rectangle From Four Way but When I want To Make Rectangle Smaller From One Side Of Rectangle I get Nan value.

[image]

```
float accuracy =0.95f;
PointF pCenter = new PointF();
PointF[] lot = new PointF[4];
lot[0] = new PointF(4.6f,8.9f);
lot[1] = new PointF(4.6f, 3.2f);
lot[2] = new PointF(1.209f, 3.2f);
lot[3] = new PointF(1.209f, 8.92f);
pCenter.X = (lot[0].X + lot[1].X) / 2;
pCenter.Y = (lot[0].Y + lot[1].Y) / 2;
//IF I write This it Works Fine
//pCenter.X = (lot[0].X + lot[1].X+ lot[2].X+ lot[3].X) / 4;
//pCenter.Y = (lot[0].Y + lot[1].Y+ lot[2].Y+ lot[3].Y) / 4;
float dx;
float dy;
for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
{
    var p = lot[ii];
    dx = p.X - pCenter.X;
    dy = p.Y - pCenter.Y;
    float add = dx * accuracy;
    float x = pCenter.X + add;
    float y = pCenter.Y + dy * (x - pCenter.X) / dx;
    lot[ii] = new PointF(x, y);
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get NAN?

Comment: float y = pCenter.Y + dy * (x - pCenter.X) / dx; because x is Equal to pCenter.X

Comment: Division by zero with dx after `dx = p.X - pCenter.X;`

Comment: I know Maybe When X is Zero I must Do other Calculation

Comment: Just make sure you're not trying to divide by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To scale a rectangle as you suggest, a loop is not necessary. It is also not necessary to calculate the center. You could use, for example, the following function. I have enumerated the points of the rectangle (p0, p1, p2, and p3) in the same order as you:

```
private void scaleRectangle(Rectangle r, float scale) {

    float width = r.p1.X - r.p2.X;

    r.p2.X = r.p1.X - width * scale;
    r.p3.X = r.p0.X - width * scale;
}
```

Comment: I change inner For This WAY and This Work.Giv ME u Opinion I am not Good At Math: var p = lot[ii];
                dx = p.X - pCenter.X;
                dy = p.Y - pCenter.Y;
                float add = dx * ParkingInfo.Accuracy;
                float x = pCenter.X + (p.X - pCenter.X) * ParkingInfo.Accuracy;
                float y = pCenter.Y + (p.Y - pCenter.Y) * ParkingInfo.Accuracy;
                lot[ii] = new PointF(x, y);

Comment: Your algorithm is incorrect. In your loop, you are modifying the values of all the points (p0, p1, p2 and p3), when only two points (p2 and p3) should be modified. Also, you are declaring variables that are never used: _dx_, _dy_, and _daa_.